# What does a glowing enemy name mean?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2, xenoblade-2-torna-golden-country

In *Xenoblade Chronicles 2: Torna ~ The Golden Country*, what does it mean when an enemy's name and health bar starts glowing blue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An enemy's name will glow blue when they have [Elemental Awakening](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Elemental_Awakening), a status that has a chance of triggering when certain enemies are given an elemental orb.

[image: Activating Elemental Awakening]
<sub>*Footage from [Chuggaconroy: Xenoblade Chronicles 2 – Episode 195 (29:12)](https://youtu.be/wRikWkzXRFY?t=1752)*</sub>

According to the [Xenoblade Wiki](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Elemental_Awakening):

> Elemental Awakening is a Status in Xenoblade Chronicles 2. It can only be used by Bosses in Challenge Battle Mode, and some enemies in Torna ~ The Golden Country, mainly Unique Monsters.
>
> It is activated when the enemy gains an elemental orb - through finishing a Blade Combo, or through placing one with the assistance of a common blade with the Orb Master skill, or through using a Special (in Torna ~ The Golden Country). Elemental Awakening has a set chance to trigger depending on whether the enemy is Enraged or not.
>
> When active, the enemy deals more damage, recharges Arts faster, and makes Blade Combos wear off much faster. The strength of each effect varies between each of the different Awakening tiers. The status can be removed by using a Chain Attack to burst all Elemental Orbs, or by using Monado Purge.

I determined the glow's cause by searching gameplay footage to find examples of glowing blue enemy names. I noticed the glowing coincided with an "Elemental Awakening" text box briefly appearing. I was then able to recreate the glowing effect in my own game.